# How to run task using sudo

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I'd like to create a task in VS Code for starting/stopping my postgres server. Is it possible to run a task using sudo?

For example, `sudo service postgresql start`?

I've tried the following launch config but it fails with an error that it can't load such file.

```
        {
            "name": "Start Postgres server",
            "type": "Ruby",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "sudo service postgresql start"
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change the `type` property from `Ruby` to the `shell`.

```
        {
        "name": "Start Postgres server",
        "type": "shell",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "sudo service postgresql start"
        }
```

[Read more about tasks here.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks)